# Parse matrix from XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, numpy, matrix

Let's say I have a matrix stored in an XML-file in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Matrix>
    <Value Col="0" Row="0">0.19343</Value>
    <Value Col="1" Row="0">0.95079</Value>
    <Value Col="2" Row="0">0.89542</Value>
    <Value Col="0" Row="1">0.14391</Value>
    <Value Col="1" Row="1">0.094629</Value>
    <Value Col="2" Row="1">0.52303</Value>
</Matrix>
```

What is the best way to parse these values into a numpy array using xml.etree in Python *without knowing the size of the dimensions of the matrix*? Otherwise, I guess i could just simply do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np

rowcnt = 2
colcnt = 3

xmltree = ET.parse('some_xmlfile.xml')
matrix = np.zeros(shape=(rowcnt, colcnt))

for m in xmltree.iter('Matrix'):
    for v in m.iter('Value'):
        col = int(v.attrib['Col'])
        row = int(v.attrib['Row'])
        matrix[row, col] = float(v.text)
    print matrix
```

Comment: Check for the second occurrence of col="0". Then preceding one will tell you how many columns there are.

Comment: Ok, so the last occurrence of `row=` will tell me the number of rows. However, this approach heavily relies on the 'correct' order of columns and rows in the XML file. Might not be the most fool-proof apporach...

Comment: Yes. Dividing the total number of elements by the maximum number denoting the row, if not put last, plus some unvoiced assumptions about your data, is another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not claiming that this is the *best* way to create a numpy array from your XML file, but this should work for an arbitrary number of columns (although the rows must be the same size), and for arbitrarily ordered `<Value>` elements.

```
import numpy as np
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

root = ET.parse('some_xmlfile.xml').getroot()

data = defaultdict(list)

# group into rows of (col, val) tuples
for val in root.iter('Value'):
    data[int(val.attrib['Row'])].append((int(val.attrib['Col']), val.text))

# sort columns and format into a space separated string
rows = []
for row in data:
    rows.append(' '.join([cols[1] for cols in sorted(data[row])]))

# build array from matrix string
matrix = np.array(np.mat(';'.join(rows)))


>>> matrix
array([[ 0.19343 ,  0.95079 ,  0.89542 ],
       [ 0.14391 ,  0.094629,  0.52303 ]])
```